# Web Config Transforms: Insert if app setting value is true or false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform

I am attempting to apply a transform based upon a app-setting value in my web.config for my asp.net MVC project.

```
<!--web.config-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Feature.GlobalSSLRedirect" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I want the transform below to insert a new element within the customHeaders element when the app-setting value Feature.GlobalSSLRedirect is true.

```
<!--web.release.config-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Condition(configuration/appSettings/add[@key='Feature.GlobalSSLRedirect']/@value = 'true')" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to use an XPath query to pick out the app-setting value and use that as a condition to decide whether to insert the XML that I want within the customHeaders element. I have tried many different variations of the XPath query, but have not managed to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be much simpilier to just define multiple publishing profiles that you can have set the appropriate transformations depending on where/how you want to publish.  Once you define the new publishing profiles, right click your web.config and select "Add Transformations".